# Boost serialization and namespace

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I'm new using Boost serialization. I'm using xml serialization and the non intrusive version. I followed the tutorial (from Boost website) step by step and my code works fine.

The problem arise when I put my class (the code is divided in .h and .cpp plus a main.cpp file) in a **namespace** (ns_mytests). In this case the compiler (g++) complains and I have the following errors:

```
g++ -c -g test.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/sources/test.o sources/test.cpp
/opt/local/include/boost/serialization/split_free.hpp: In static member function 'static void boost::serialization::free_saver<Archive, T>::invoke(Archive&, const T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive, T = ns_mytests::Test]':
/opt/local/include/boost/serialization/split_free.hpp:74:   instantiated from 'void boost::serialization::split_free(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive, T = ns_mytests::Test]'
sources/test.h:117:   instantiated from 'void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive&, ns_mytests::Test&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive]'
/opt/local/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:128:   instantiated from 'void boost::serialization::serialize_adl(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive, T = ns_mytests::Test]'
/opt/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:148:   instantiated from 'void boost::archive::detail::oserializer<Archive, T>::save_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive&, const void*) const [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_oarchive, T = ns_mytests::Test]'
sources/test.cpp:146:   instantiated from here
/opt/local/include/boost/serialization/split_free.hpp:45: error: no matching function for call to 'save(boost::archive::xml_oarchive&, const ns_mytests::Test&, const boost::serialization::version_type&)'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/sources/test.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

It's sure that I'm doing wrong something, but I could't find my error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
westfork

Comment: It says quite clearly that it's trying to invoke a function with the signature `save(boost::archive::xml_oarchive&, ns_mytests::Test const&, boost::serialization::version_type const&)` -- do you have such a function? If you do, what namespace is _it_ in? (_Hint_, _hint_, show your code, not just your errors.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes it was a problem with namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the non-intrusive `save` in the namespace where the type to be serialized is defined.

Comment: You are welcome. Please feel free to mark the answer properly if it was of any help.